# Реализация отрицательного рейтинга на PHP

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица rating, в ней столбец value, в который записывается одно значение, единица или ноль.
То есть если пользователь ставит `+`, в бд пишется 1, если `-`, то пишется 0.

Как получить сумму, понятно, а как сделать, чтобы у объекта был отрицательный рейтинг, то есть 0 приравнивался к -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посчитайте количество нулей и умножьте на -1.